# Использование groupby в Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

Есть данные типа df

```
фрукт   сорт  цена
яблоко голден 15 грн
яблоко зеленое 20 грн
яблоко раннее  23 грн
виноград белый 50 грн
виноград киш-миш 35 грн
```

мне нужно получить: фрукт, сорт по максимальной цене, то есть:

```
яблоко раннее  23 грн
виноград белый 50 грн
```

Если пробую `df.groupby('фрукт').цена.max()`, тогда не получается подтянуть сорт по максимальной цене

Comment: [Добавте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/715873/edit) в вопрос код, где у вас возникли затруднения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас сразу несколько "проблематичных" мест:

основная проблема - цена у вас в виде строки и поэтому сортировка будет производиться в [лексикографическом порядке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA). Т.е. `'9 грн'` будет больше чем `'1000 грн'`.

другая сложность в использовании `max()`, т.к. вы хотите также видеть `сорт`  - в этом случае лучше воспользоваться [DataFrame.nlargest()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html)

Пример:

```
df.assign(x=pd.to_numeric(df['цена'].str.replace(r'[^\d\.]+',''), errors='coerce')) \
  .groupby('фрукт', group_keys=False) \
  .apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(1, 'x').drop('x',1))
```

Результат:

```
      фрукт    сорт    цена
3  виноград   белый  50 грн
2    яблоко  раннее  23 грн
```

Вспомогательный столбец `x` - `цена` с числовым типом:

```
In [68]: df.assign(x=pd.to_numeric(df['цена'].str.replace(r'[^\d\.]+',''),
    ...:                           errors='coerce'))
    ...:
Out[68]:
      фрукт     сорт    цена   x
0    яблоко   голден  15 грн  15
1    яблоко  зеленое  20 грн  20
2    яблоко   раннее  23 грн  23
3  виноград    белый  50 грн  50
4  виноград  киш-миш  35 грн  35
```

Но более идиоматично (правильно) - будет разбить столбец `цена` на два: `цена` (числового типа) и `валюта`:

```
In [92]: df[['цена','валюта']] = df['цена'].str.split(n=1, expand=True)

In [93]: df['цена'] = pd.to_numeric(df['цена'], errors='coerce')

In [94]: df
Out[94]:
      фрукт     сорт  цена валюта
0    яблоко   голден    15    грн
1    яблоко  зеленое    20    грн
2    яблоко   раннее    23    грн
3  виноград    белый    50    грн
4  виноград  киш-миш    35    грн

In [95]: df.dtypes
Out[95]:
фрукт     object
сорт      object
цена       int64
валюта    object
dtype: object
```

после этого решение будет выглядеть проще:

```
In [97]: df.groupby('фрукт', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(1, 'цена'))
Out[97]:
      фрукт    сорт  цена валюта
3  виноград   белый    50    грн
2    яблоко  раннее    23    грн
```

Comment: Да, так все получилось. Спасибо большое :)

Comment: @Марина, пожалуйста! :) В SO сообществе приветствуется [принятие ответа (отметить ответ как верный)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) в том случае если автор вопроса считает, что получил исчерпывающий ответ. Это также показывает, что на данный вопрос был дан ответ, который удовлетворяет автора вопроса и вопрос не "висит" неотвеченным...

Comment: Я бы с удовольствием отметила как верный, но относительно новичок здесь, и не совсем знаю как это сделать (((  нажимаю на стрелочку вверх (ответ полезен), напротив Вашего ответа, мне пишет что мои голоса начнут влиять на рейтинг когда порог будет превышен 15 баллов. Может я не там отмечаю? :(

Comment: да, я там и нажимаю. Итог: "Спасибо за ваш отзыв! Ваши голоса начнут влиять на рейтинг сообщений, как только ваша репутация превысит порог в 15 баллов."

Comment: Все, отметила ) спасибо Вам еще раз :)

Comment: @Марина, был рад помочь! :)